# Laravel 8: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Migration like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('link');
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->string('actor');
            $table->string('director');
            $table->integer('imdb');
            $table->boolean('watched')->default(0);
            $table->integer('starred');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But when I want to store some data into this table, I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value**

Here is my `store` method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new = new Movie();
        $new->name = $request->name;
        $new->link = $request->link;
        $new->year = $request->year;
        $new->actor = $request->actor;
        $new->director = $request->director;
        $new->imdb = $request->imdb;
        $new->starred = $request->starred;
        $new->watched = $request->watched;
        $new->save();
    }
```

I don't know what is going wrong here, that shows me this error... If you know, plz let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:** Result of `dd($request)`:

[image]

**UPDATE #2:** Full error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
> format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column
> `bia2film`.`movies`.`watched` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `movies`
> (`name`, `link`, `year`, `actor`, `director`, `imdb`, `starred`,
> `watched`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Godfather, asdsadsa,
> 1232, Brando, Copola, 9, 5, on, 2021-04-30 13:41:20, 2021-04-30
> 13:41:20))

Comment: can you dd your request? `dd($request);` and show us the result

Comment: Which value triggers this error? Please, post full error messages in questions, don't cut them off. There are two integer fields and we don't know what's in your request.

Comment: @Jack I just added it...

Comment: @El_Vanja `Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column `bia2film`.`movies`.`watched` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `movies` (`name`, `link`, `year`, `actor`, `director`, `imdb`, `starred`, `watched`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Godfather, asdsadsa, 1232, Brando, Copola, 9, 5, on, 2021-04-30 13:41:20, 2021-04-30 13:41:20))`

Comment: @El_Vanja See **Update #2** plz

Comment: `$table->boolean('watched')->default(0);` but you try to store a string `'on'`.

Comment: `$new->watched = ($request->watched === 'on');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from Your Screenshot You are trying to store a string value to the boolean column

```
$table->boolean('watched')->default(0);
```

Try To change Your Schema  from

```
        $table->boolean('watched')->default(0);
    to
    
         $table->enum('watched',['on','off'])->default('off');
```

or Change  the  value  of request to `True` or `false`.

I prefer Sencond method

Comment: or, if is it a checkbox, value="1". But take care that if is not checked the value is not passed in the $request